# Which finite groups have exactly 2 conjugacy classes of the same order and exactly 2 irreducible characters of the same degree?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Dears

I have a interesting question,

Let G be a finite group with exactly 2 conjugacy class of the same order.
when degrees of exactly 2 irreducible characters are equivalent?

Comment: Changed the tags, as the question has nothing to do with characteristic classes.

Comment: Seems to work for A_5 and PSL(2,7). But it does not work for A_4. The condition is quite restrictive and I am not sure if there is a clean general statement.

Comment: Doesn't work for dihedral group of order 10; conjugacy classes have orders 1, 2, 2, 5, irreducible characters have degrees 1, 1, 2, 2. 

Comment: Also doesn't work for $S_4$ and $S_5$ (class lengths 1,3,6,6,8 vs degrees 1,1,2,3,3 and 1,10,15,20,20,24,30 vs 1,1,4,4,5,5,6).

Comment: What's the motivation for this question? http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask#motivation